# Passing value from c# textbox to html page?

Tags: c#, html

How to send text value from c# textbox to the webpage?
I have implemented the connection code:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 String url="the url of the webpage"
 Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
```

The webpage contains a textbox and button....now i want to invoke both(textbox and button) from c# client application...how to implement that?

now i got the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say pass text value..? are you talking about passing the value in .aspx, inside of a button click event..? be more specific

Comment: if i enter a value say"123" in my c# textbox.. i need to receive the value 123 in the textbox in my webpage....can this be done?

Comment: are you mixing C# web Forms with win forms.. or is the textbox on the webpage that you are entering `123`..? you really need to be more specific.. your example is at very low quality at best..

Comment: no i have created a webpage using forms with textbox and button....i also have a c# win forms with textbox and button....now i want to pass value from c# win form to form in my webpage..

Comment: I would suggest using / creating a web service, or you could store the information in a Database and consume a web service to return the data.. or if you are familiar with UDP or sockets you could do it that way.. which I don't think you would want to do.. you could convert the application into Silverlight or WPF as well

Comment: look at this example if you are hard set on sending data from WinForm to a WebForm http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/free-geocoder-us-web-service-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: here is an example from the article where you can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to send the textbox data as a param follow this example `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe","http://yoursite.com/&text=" + textbox.Text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1- Create a web page like www.test.com/default.aspx

2- Pass a querystring parameter like www.test.com/default.aspx?**textboxvalue=123**

3- In the Page_load of the default.aspx assign the query string value to the webpage textbox

4- Call the webpage from the your application like

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
 String url=@"www.test.com/default.aspx?textboxvalue=" + [Your textbox value]
  Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
```

EDIT:

If you donot have the access to the code then you are probably looking to automate the webpage. To automate you can use the http://watin.org/.

Here is the sample code

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
  }
```

Comment: That assumes he has access to the source code of the page, which I cannot deduce from his question.

Comment: what if he is wanting to pass the text box value to a different page, then you would need to account for the response.redirect something like this `responce.redirect("page.aspx?text=value");` it's really hard to provide a valid solution until the OP provides more information

Comment: I have added the web page automation example also.

Comment: i got this error .....The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Which method are you using ? the first one or the second one ? and do you have access to the web application where you want to put the value of the textbox ?

Comment: the webpage is protected one...in order to access it i need to provide credentials....through gmail...

Comment: Post a separate questions about this issue because the question you are asking now, is different then your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use QueryString to pass in the value to the page.

URL becomes--> Url?ValueForPage=txtBox.Text